# rails executable source code repository

Tags: initialization, ruby-on-rails-5

The `rails` in the command `rails server` is ruby executable. Is there a source code repository for this file? And which program installs it in my load path?

Comment: You might like https://leanpub.com/ddr

Comment: yes I have a copy of "deep dive rails", though it covers Rails 4 and not Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a source code repository for this file?

Is the `bin\rails` copied from the railties into your new project when you've run `rails new` (ie. [the `app` generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb)). Source is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/exe/rails). It simply invokes [`rails/cli`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/cli.rb)

> And which program installs it in my load path?

Original rails 'command' is installed by `gem install rails`

Comment: yes the ruby executable('rails') is  generated by RubyGems, I did not read the comments in the file :(.